# 'QtSharedPointer' has not been declared

Tags: qt6

```
qPointerFromVariant(const QVariant &variant)
{
    const auto wp = QtSharedPointer::weakPointerFromVariant_internal(variant);
    return QPointer<T>{qobject_cast<T*>(QtPrivate::EnableInternalData::internalData(wp))};
}
```

W:/SoftWares/Qt/QT6/6.6.0/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qpointer.h An error occurred

Comment: Do you have `#include <QSharedPointer>`?  If that doesn't fix the problem then you need to provide more info: starting with the complete error message(s) as text verbatim and more context regarding the code causing the problem.